$A$ doesn't have a minimum and $B$ doesn't have a supreme
This is my first question here.
The exercise:
For any pair of sets $A, B$ such that they meet the next conditions:
$A \cup B \subseteq (0, + \infty)$
$10 ∈ A ∩ B$.
If $x ∈ A$, then for all $y ∈ (0, +∞)$ such that $y < x$ then $y ∈ A$.
If $x ∈ B$, then for all $y ∈ (0, +∞)$ such that $y > x$ then $y ∈ B$.
So, my teacher said that:
$(0,10]⊆A$ because $10 ∈ A$ and for all $y∈ (0,+∞)$ with $y<10$ such that $y∈A$ then $\inf(A)=0$ and it cannot be minimum because $A \subseteq (0,+∞)$.
On the other hand:
$[10,+∞)⊆B$ because $10 ∈ B$ and for all $y∈ (0,+∞)$ with $y>10$ such that $y∈B$ then $B$ doesn't have a supreme (is not upper bounded) and also $B$ is lower bounded by $0$ then there exist an $inf(B)$ but we don't know which one is $inf(B)$ and neither if it is a minimum.
Conclusion:
$A$ doesn't have a minimum and $B$ doesn't have a supreme.
My question is:
Why did my teacher take $(0,10]⊆A$ and $[10,+∞)⊆B$ ? Is it not possible to have other subsets inside of A or B such that it doesn't have to be those intervals? And what tells me I can't have $10<y<x$ in $A$ and $x<y<10$ in $B$?
Sorry if there is any mistake, I'm not a native English speaker.

You for got all if's in the proof. So read slower to find out what is supposed in every part.

We know that $10\in A\cap B$ so $10\in A$ and $10\in B$. Since all numbers less than $10$ are in $A$, $(-\infty, 10]\subset A$. Likewise, $[10,\infty)\subset B$.
